# Unable to connect to VPN 800 error message

Tags: vpn

I have scoured the internet and nothing has helped me. I am able to connect to the unversity VPN on other LANs such as my home(where im from) but at my home at uni it won't connect - i receive the error message 800. So clearly it is an issue with the router and or how my PC is configured to this particular network.

The password and username is 100% not the issue (because i'm able to connect everywhere else)

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

VPN Error 800 is one of the most common errors that occur while connecting to VPN.
It gives error message that says “Unable to establish the VPN connection. The VPN server may be un-reachable, or security parameters may not be configured properly for this connection.”

Reasons responsible for VPN Error 800 :

- Your router’s firmware is not up to date.
- Firewall may be blocking the connection.
- VPN tunnel type is set to automatic.

How you can fix VPN error 800:
As you mentioned Password and username is not the issue then you can check other settings such as:

- Router and Firewall settings.
- PPTP port settings.
- Try pinging the server.

For more details you can refer : http://www.itrickbuzz.com/vpn-error-800-windows-7-8-8-1/

Hope this helps.